# Warning for rm -r command

Tags: bash, shell

I want `rm` to prompt me when recursively deleting a directory, as in:

```
$ rm -r <dir>
Do you want to remove the dir(Y/N)?
```

Is there an argument I can pass to `rm` that will do this?

Comment: And what if you give several arguments, some dirs, and others regular files?

Comment: Try `rm -i` command

Comment: Well zsh shell has this kind of warning for rm -rf *

Comment: "I usually like to alias `rm` to `rm -rf`, so that it gets easier to remove a directory" -- right, because `rm -f` isn't quite dangerous enough.

Comment: In general, "please write this thing for me" questions aren't welcome on StackOverflow -- and neither are "how do I configure this non-programming-related tool that comes with my operating system?"

Comment: Keith Thompson is right: You should seriously reconsider this alias. Best do it before you accidentally wipe your home directory...

Comment: However, that doesn't warrant minus 1-ing his question.  You're not supposed to flag or downvote based on motive.  Maybe you should suggest aliasing `rmdir` instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The essence of his question is totally valid, I made some edits to help it comply with guidelines

Comment: @ErlVolton, questions about available arguments for `rm` belong on SuperUser, or http://unix.stackexchange.com/, not StackOverflow.

Comment: OK, so let's help him get his question moved to somewhere more relevant and explain why we're doing that.  TBH I've got no idea how to get a question moved, can you lend a hand?

Comment: @cmaster thankyou for your suggestion ,I have changed it now.

Comment: On a different part, by the way -- `rm` is provided by your operating system, not by bash. This means that this probably shouldn't be tagged bash (whether you're using bash or some other shell has no bearing on your `rm` command's available options or flags), but *should* be tagged with the specific operating system you're using.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: before the edits, the post was asking _Can some one give me a simple script to add for my `.bashrc`?_. Hence the Bash tag. Question was also mentioning an alias.

Comment: @ErlVolton, ...I missed your edit; re: getting a question moved, voting to close with a reason from the migration category will have that effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is uppercase `-I`, as in:

```
$ rm -rI tg/
rm: remove all arguments recursively?
```

As noted in the comments, this is something nice [GNU's `rm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/rm-invocation.html) is giving you, and not required based on the [posix spec for `rm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html).

Comment: Which platform is this valid on? (It's not in the POSIX spec for `rm`; is it GNU? Mac? ...?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy GNU does it. I don't know about other systems, though.

Comment: I highly recommend that you don't *alias* either one of these, but instead build yourself the habit of using the option you want.  If you do an alias, and get used to it, and then you're on a system that doesn't have the alias, you'll be in for an unpleasant surprise when your rm -r suddenly removes everything, without asking.

Comment: I agree, however I think `rmdir` is sort of OK because on another system it would just refuse to remove anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what OS you're on, there's `rm -i` (which will prompt for each individual file) or perhaps `rm -I` (part of GNU rm), which, per the man page, will *"prompt  once  before  removing  more  than three files, or when removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes"*

I highly recommend *against* creating an alias for this, and instead build the habit of using one or the other of the above options.  Being on a system without the alias you've gotten used to can create much grief (removing files you didn't intend to remove).  Using the habitual option when you actually don't want it just means a minor annoyance (being prompted a few times, and either answering yes to each prompt, or breaking out (<kbd>C-c</kbd>) and starting again without the option).  The latter is much less painful, I find.

Comment: He doesn't want lowercase `-i`, he specifically asked for a single prompt.  Also you'll notice the question was updated a while ago to remove everything about aliases

Comment: Well, he may not have the option of `rm -I`, so that's why I included it in my answer.  I see you've updated you *answer* to remove the aliasing (I guess thanks to my comment; maybe I should have left it at that; I never saw it in the question), so this answer becomes a bit redundant now.  Perhaps I'll withdraw it; certainly, I'll now upvote your answer, now that it doesn't suggest using an alias.